# How to clean memory while parsing in python

Tags: python, memory, beautifulsoup

I've got a simple 2-step parsing script written in Python 3 working like this:

1) The function given a URL parses it with BeautifullSoup, collects all needed data in simple Pandas Series then returns it:

```
def parse(url):
    ...fill in Series
    return Series
```

2) I've got a huge list of URLs (over 50K items) which I work with in a loop:

```
for url in urls:
    dataframe.append(parse(url))
```

When the script runs memory usage increases a lot (like 5 GB after only 20 minutes).

How do I properly clean memory or maybe downloaded cache after each iteration?

Comment: Try processing everything lazily. It's hard to say much more though without more context.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by saying "processing everything lazily"?

Comment: Using generators so you dont hold everything in memory at once. Have the results produced by a generator instead of dumping everything into a list all at once.

Comment: Use generators first solution, second is writing it to a file line by line meaning again generating it into a file (exporting) or just process something and then it will be automatically deleted by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys if you struggle the same problem:

1) Make sure you use soup.decompose() after done with it
2) Of course i made a mistake when i tried to fill all the data in one pd.DataFrame before saving it to file. Now i get a small tmp dataframe, once i get around fixed amount of rows i save it then clear tmp.

Now process uses around 200 mb of ram maximum.

That's it, hope that help anyone.